# Multiple classes how best to proceed

Tags: php, subclass

I have the following working in some respect, I can access smarty with $db->tpl in my scripts.

**init.php included at the top of each file**

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'inc/classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});

class Database_Smarty extends Smarty {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->setTemplateDir('templates'); // etc etc

    }

}

class Filter_Database extends Database {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
    }

}

class Formatting_Database extends Database {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
    }

}

class Hashing_Database extends Database {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

**Database.class.php** 
This works just fine i can access smarty from my database object. My problem comes when i try to add Formatting_Database or any of the following extends into the construct.

```
class Database {

    // vars instantiated
    public $tpl;
    public $fmt;

    public function __construct() {
        # Connection here works

        $this->tpl = new Database_Smarty;

        // Example i cant do this it crashed php leading to no data
        // sent notice in the browser.
        $this->fmt = new Formatting_Database;

    }
}
```

**Formatting.class.php** The rest of the class files follow the same format.

```
class Formatting {

    public $fmt;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->fmt = new Formatting_Database;
    }
```

Can anybody point out what it is i need to change to access Formatting class from the $db object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One word: recursion.

What is presumably happening is:

```
new Database;
[calls __construct on Database]
    [calls __construct on Formatting_Database]
        [calls __construct on parent (Database)]
             [calls __construct on Formatting_Database]
                 [calls __construct on parent (Database)] 
                     [calls __construct on Formatting_Database]
                         [calls __construct on parent (Database)]
(for ever and ever and ever)
```

I'm not sure why PHP isn't reporting a stack overflow in this case, but that is presumably where it's heading.

Try removing the line here and observing behaviour:

```
// Example i cant do this it crashed php leading to no data
// sent notice in the browser.
$this->fmt = new Formatting_Database;
```

So I think you need to rethink your design a bit, the precise solution will depend on exactly what needs to happen obviously!

Just a final extra note... you might want to look at require vs include vs include_once vs require_once, unless my knowledge is outdated this will make a difference when including files (include_once won't re-import a second time) -- again, depends on how everything is bolted together but worth checking.

Comment: Sorry misfired. Adding that line (i only added it again here to show what i tried already) causes the crash.

Essentially what im aiming at in the long run us to have all of my $db and $db->tpl objects direct through filter or format as required depending on where its going. so user data will be filtered for the database and the data when pulled back out it filtered and formatted for browser output.

Im just getting myself into a mess with the ordering of the classes i think.

Comment: @Chris I think this will need a bit more than a comment to suggest a solution to the design problem. Have a look at: http://www.oodesign.com it's a good resource on some patterns that you could use. For me it would be pen+paper(+tea & biscuit) time!!

Comment: Ive gone back to the drawing board on it, i did finally manage to recursively add each class but it seems cumbersome and in the long term problematic to refactor if needed so im going to look at the link suggested and take good notes :), thanks for your help.